# UIView not showing in both header views

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, tableview

I am developing an `iPad` application. For some reasons, I need to show a `two tableviews` in the same view controller. I have created a `UIView` in a `xib` and connected a `outlet` to that `view controller`. I need to show that view in those two tableviews as a `tableHeaderView`. When I try to assign that view to `both header views`, it is showing only in the `second tableview`.I hope there is a single instance for that view. So it is showing on only in the view, which I assigned last. How could I overcome this??  Any help would be appreciated.

Here it is my code.

```
[energyTableView setTableHeaderView:tableHeader];
[maintenanceTableView setTableHeaderView:tableHeader];
```

@CodeBySteveZ

As he said, I created an xib and tried. And still I can't get the solution. Am I doing anything wrong??here it is how I tried.

```
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"tableHeaderCell" owner:nil options:nil];

[energyTableView setTableHeaderView:[topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0]];
[maintenanceTableView setTableHeaderView:[topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0]];
```

I think this is also a same thing as I did before.

Comment: 1 view == 1 superview, you cant use it in two places at once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to create another instance of the tableHeader. A UIView can only live in one visual sub-tree at a time. Using IB you could copy the element and create 2 instances of it. Or if you create a separate xib with that just element you could load that particular xib twice via code, once for each table header.

Comment: You mean I need to copy and paste the same uiview and connect outlet to that view with another name and set as tableViewHeader?? If that so, then I am gonna need another same view. Can't I reuse the same view in a code itself? I think there will be some other solution.

Comment: There isn't a way to clone an existing element. So yes you'd need another IBOutlet to associate with the other copy of the view in your xib.

Comment: Ok I will do like this. But I am gonna wait, if I can get some other good solution than this. Thank you so much.

Comment: there is no "other good solution than this".  A UIView object can not have more than one superview.  Therefore you need have two instances of this view you're speaking of, and therefore this answer is the answer to your question.  Don't wait, code now! :))

Answer (score 0):

@R.A I know its tedious to go programmatically but u can try this

```
 UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(XXX, YYY, XXX, YYY)];
 UILabel *labelView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(XXX, YYY, XXX, YYY)];
 [headerView addSubview:labelView];
 energyTableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

Similarly add to other tableview a den release it.

```
 [labelView release];
 [headerView release];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

one view can not appear in two places.... said simplified
one view == one superview