# Tab bar items are the same except for their data set in storyboard

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I've set up a storyboard with a UITabBarController object and I'd like to add two tabs to that, but both tabs are going to be exactly the same except for the data they will display. Obviously, I could drag in two new view controllers and connect them up and just maintain the views separately, but I don't want to do this at all.

Does anyone know the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: you need to have separate views in both view controllers. You cannot use the same view as for the both view controllers.Because a view cannot have two superviews. I think my question will make clear things to you. http://stackoverflow.com/q/13322143/1083859

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this by using a regular UIViewController with a tab bar at the bottom, rather than using a UITabBarController. You just have to use the UITabBar delegate method, tabBar:didSelectItem:, to detect the tab clicks, and then do whatever you need to do to switch what data is displayed in the single view.

Comment: I've decided to abandon storyboards for this project, but I did try this out and do feel like this is the best way to do this if you wish to stick with storyboards.